# Merge maps inside list in terraform

Tags: for-loop, terraform

I have a list of maps like this -

```
[
  {
    "outer_key_1" = [
      {
        "ip_cidr" = "172.16.6.0/24"
        "range_name" = "range1"
      },
      {
        "ip_cidr" = "172.16.7.0/24"
        "range_name" = "range2"
      },
      {
        "ip_cidr" = "172.17.6.0/24"
        "range_name" = "range3"
      },
      {
        "ip_cidr" = "172.17.7.0/24"
        "range_name" = "range4"
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    "outer_key_2" = [
      {
        "ip_cidr" = "172.16.5.0/24"
        "range_name" = "range5"
      },
      {
        "ip_cidr" = "172.17.5.0/24"
        "range_name" = "range6"
      },
    ]
  },
]
```

I want to merge the maps inside the list. This is in an output variable `module.module_name.module_op`.

Required Output:

```
{
    "outer_key_1" = [
      {
        "ip_cidr" = "172.16.6.0/24"
        "range_name" = "range1"
      },
      {
        "ip_cidr" = "172.16.7.0/24"
        "range_name" = "range2"
      },
      {
        "ip_cidr" = "172.17.6.0/24"
        "range_name" = "range3"
      },
      {
        "ip_cidr" = "172.17.7.0/24"
        "range_name" = "range4"
      },
    ]

    "outer_key_2" = [
      {
        "ip_cidr" = "172.16.5.0/24"
        "range_name" = "range5"
      },
      {
        "ip_cidr" = "172.17.5.0/24"
        "range_name" = "range6"
      },
    ]
}
```

I have done this using

```
locals {
  result = merge(module.module_name.module_op[0], module.module_name.module_op[1])
}
```

How do I do this in a more iterative way.

I will not always only 2 maps in my list, it can be more.

I tried using the for loop in terraform 12 like this -

```
output "result" {
  value = [ for tuple in module.module_name.module_op : merge(tuple) ]
}
```

and this -

```
output "secondary_subnets" {
  value = { for tuple in module.module_name.module_op : merge(tuple) }
}
```

The first one gives me my input back and the second one gives me an error saying I need to add a key since I am returning an object.

Is there a way to get this done?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You can actually pass a list of maps to the `merge()` function:

> The Terraform language has a general feature for turning lists/tuples into multiple arguments, by using the special symbol `...` after the last argument expression

So, in your example above, you could do:

```
locals {
  result = merge(module.module_name.module_op...)
}
```

This will then merge all of the maps in the list, allowing for dynamically sized lists.

Comment: Thank you so much! All I could find in the terraform documentation were [Splat Expressions](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/expressions/splat.html), which return a tuple, and are therefore incompatible with `merge()`.

Comment: Thank you very much. Is this mentioned ANYWHERE in terraform documentation ? Only way I found it is to google closed issue opened on terraform github.

Comment: @DanielHajduk It is defined in the HCL spec: https://github.com/hashicorp/hcl/blob/main/hclsyntax/spec.md#functions-and-function-calls  Would be nice if it was mentioned in the terraform docs though.

Comment: Terraform's function argument expansion is briefly documented at: https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/function-calls#expanding-function-arguments.  I've updated the answer with the caveat more clearly stated and link.

Answer (score 11):

Unfortunately, the `values()` of your maps are lists. Otherwise you could do the following which will work for `list(map(<not_list>))`:

e.g.

```
locals {
  my_list_of_maps = [
    {
       key1 = "val1"
       key2 = "val2"
    },
    {
       key3 = "val3"
    },
  ]
}

zipmap(
  flatten(
    [for item in local.my_list_of_maps : keys(item)]
  ),
  flatten(
    [for item in local.my_list_of_maps : values(item)]
  )
)
```

this will process like so

```
zipmap(
  flatten([["key1", "key2"], ["key3"]]),
  flatten([["val1", "val2"], ["val3"]])
)
```

=>

```
zipmap(
  ["key1", "key2", "key3"],
  ["val1", "val2", "val3"]
)
```

=>

```
{
  key1 = "val1"
  key2 = "val2"
  key3 = "val3"
}
```

i have used a simple `list(map(string))` here but the `values()` of the map can be more complex. however, since `flatten()` is used (which flattens nested lists recursively), the `values()` cannot be lists themselves.

in order to get this to work, you could always transform your data to look like this instead:

```
[
  {
    "outer_key_1" = {
      range1 = "172.16.6.0/24"
      range2 = "172.16.7.0/24"
      range3 = "172.17.6.0/24"
      range4 = "172.17.7.0/24"
    }
  },
  {
    "outer_key_2" = {
      range5 = "172.16.5.0/24"
      range6 = "172.17.5.0/24"
    }
  },
]
```

the above logic will work for that without a problem.

by the way, `zipmap()` behaves like a `merge()`. so if there are duplicate keys, the late arrivals will overwrite the existing keys.

Comment: you can transform your data like so:
`[for outer in <input> : {for key, val in outer : key => {for inner in val : inner["range_name"] => inner["ip_cidr"]}}]`